# extra characters in csv output

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a Python program to convert a simple text file to a.csv file.

Each line of input contains names after `from:` followed by a name. Lines that do not start with `from:` are to be ignored.

Input:

```
from: Lance Cummins
This line is ignored by the program
from: Jackie Cohen
Hello world
from: Chris Paul
Lalala
from: Jackie Cohen
Message
```

The output of the program should be a CSV file, showing the name of the person followed by the number of times they appeared in the input file:

```
Lance Cummins,1
Chris Paul,1
Jackie Cohen,2
```

However, the actual output of the program is this:

```
["Chris Paul": 1, "Lance Cummins": 1, "Jackie Cohen": 2}
```

**What confuses me is that I had another person run my program on their computer and the result was correct. Why is this happening?**

Here is my actual program:

```
def is_field(field_name, s):
    if s[:len(field_name)] == field_name:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def contributor_counts(file_name):
    fname = open(file_name, "r" )
    counts = {}
    for x in fname: 
        if is_field("from: ", x):
            x = x.strip("from: ")
            x = x.rstrip()
            if x in counts:
                counts[x] = counts[x] + 1
            else:
                counts[x] = 1
    return counts

def print_contributors(counts):
    for x in counts:
        if counts[x] > 1:
            print str(x) + " posted " + str(counts[x]) + " times"
        else:
            print str(x) + " posted once"

def save_contributors(counts, output_file_name):
    f = open(output_file_name, "w")
    for value in counts:
        number = counts[value]
        y = str(value) + "," + str(number)
        f.write(y + "\n")
    f.close()

contributions = contributor_counts("long182feed.txt")
print_contributors(contributions)
save_contributors(contributions, 'contributors.csv')
```

Comment: Was one computer a linux/osx box and the other a PC?  Could it be related to line endings?

Comment: @NiallByrne yes I'm using both linux and windows, but the problem seems to occur in both (though I'm not sure)

Comment: Works perfectly on Windows for me.  Are you running the program in an IDE?  Perhaps the interpreter has remembered a past variable that is affecting the result?  Save your program and run it clean in a new IDE or from the command line.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I just did the same and it worked on Windows! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Is the real issue the ordering of the lines in resulting csv? Be aware that the items in a Python dictionary can be in arbitrary order. [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is available Python 2.7 onwards.

Comment: I realize that the items in the dictionary are in no particular order for Python; however, my intended output does not produce a dictionary, but rather only prints the keys and corresponding values within one.

Comment: I repeat: Is the real issue that you get the lines in the wrong order? If it is, then the reason is that you are using the dict (that may have items in arbitrary order when you print out the values).

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit Python standard library namely [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv) module and [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections#collections.Counter):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import fileinput
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for line in fileinput.input(): # read stdin or file(s) provided at a command-line
    if line.startswith('from:'): # ignore lines that do not start with 'from:'
       name = line.partition(':')[2].strip() # extract name from the line
       c[name] += 1 # count number of occurrences 

# write csv file
with open('contributors.csv', 'wb') as f:
     csv.writer(f, delimiter=',').writerows(c.most_common())
```

#### Example

```
$ python write-csv.py input.txt
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/noNxu)

```
Jackie Cohen,2
Lance Cummins,1
Chris Paul,1
```

As an alternative you could use regular expressions to parse input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import fileinput
import re
import sys
from collections import Counter

text = ''.join(fileinput.input()) # read input
c = Counter(re.findall(r'^from:\s*(.*?)\s*$', text, re.MULTILINE)) # count names
csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',').writerows(c.most_common())   # write csv
```